# умножение float

Tags: java, android, float

Помогите разобраться почему при умножении я получаю следующую ошибку:
"operator * cannot to be applied to  'java.lang.String', 'float'

```
convert.setText(String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(rubsum.getText().toString())) * Float.parseFloat(valueEur.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Ответ исправлен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(rubsum.getText().toString()))
> ```

Последняя скобка должна закрываться после умножения, а не до.

```
convert.setText(String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(rubsum.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(valueEur.getText().toString())));
```

Comment: @Freedom, прими ответ галочкой слева от него ;)

Comment: 7 минут еще подождать